# How to search an object list in c#?

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I'm still learning C# and am trying to build a list of NICs that I can later reference in my code to perform misc. functions.  Anyway, I'm able to populate the list fine, but the problem now is that I'm not sure on the best way to search through the list for NIC objects with specific criteria.  I can kind of make a foreach loop work, but I'm not sure if this is the best approach.  I've searched this topic and have found a bunch of material on how to do advanced searches using LINQ or using Lambdas, but not really any good info on these work for beginning programers.

Here's my code on creating the object and list as well as pseudocode for what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
//Constructs a NIC structure and a list to store NICs (my actual code)
struct NIC
{
    public string nicName;
    public string nicIp;
    public string nicGateway;
    public string nicMask;
}
List<NIC> nicList = new List<NIC>();




//Example searches in semi pseudocode
if nicList contains any NIC where anyNIC.nicIp first three chars .Contains("169")
{
//Do something
}


if nicList contains any NIC where anyNIC.nicIP != null 
{
//Do something
}
```

-Thanks

Answer (score 2):

LINQ is about to become your best friend. In this case, I'd use the [`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) method. `Enumerable.Any` is an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`, so you can call it directly on your `nicList`. You pass it a function that takes an instance of `NIC` and returns `true` or `false`.

Here's how it would look like in your specific case:

```
if (nicList.Any(x => x.nicIp.StartsWith("169"))
{
   // Do something
}


if (nicList.Any(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.nicIP))
{
   // Do something
}
```

In this case, `Enumerable.Any` just returns `true` if you have one or more elements that satisfy your condition. If you want to access the elements that satisfy the condition, use the LINQ method [`Enumerable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx). The signature is identical, but instead of a `bool`, it returns an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Example:

```
var nicsWithIp = nicList.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.nicIP);
```

For more information, check out this MSDN page: "[Getting Started with LINQ in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397933.aspx)".

Comment: This looks pretty good, thanks!  I'll try it later today and let you know.  I'll also look into the Getting Started with LINQ guide :)

Comment: So are these only bool results, or can I grab what it finds?  I don't seem to be able to list found IPs with:   listbox.Items.Add(n.nicIP);

Comment: @user1959800 Yeah, there's a LINQ method for that -- `Enumerable.Where`. I've updated my answer, take a look.

Answer (score 0):

use LINQ:

```
var nics = nicList.Where(n => n.nicIp.Substring(0, 3) == "169").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
if(nicList.Where(n => n.nicIp.Substring(0, 3) == "169").Any())
{

}
```

and

```
if(nicList.Where(n => n.nicIp != null).Any())
{

}
```

It may be wise to add a null check to the first one as well, to prevent a NullReferenceException:

```
if(nicList.Where(n => n.nicIp != null && n.nicIp.Substring(0, 3) == "169").Any())
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few ways to go about it using the LINQ framework.

You can use the **inline query** syntax:

```
// Get all NICs with 169.x.x.x IP address
var nic169 = from nic in nicList
              where nic.nicIp != null && nic.nicIp.StartsWith("169")
              select nic;

var contains169Ip = nic169.Count() > 0;

// Get all NICs with non-null, non-empty IP address    
var validIpNics = from nic in nicList
                   where !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nic.nicIp)
                   select nic;
```

Alternatively, you can use the **lambda syntax** with LINQ methods:

```
// Do we have a 169.x.x.x NIC present?
var has169 = nicList.Any(nic => nic.nicIp != null && nic.nicIp.StartWith("169"));

// First NIC with a non-null, non-empty IP address
var firstNic = nicList.First(nic => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nic.nicIp));
```

To better explain **lambda** expressions, take the `delegate` type of `Func<string,bool>`. This means "*a method which takes in a string and **returns** a bool value*". This method is used in the `.Any()` method as a selector to determine if **any** of the objects match.

`var func = (text) => { return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text); }`

is directly equivalent to:

`bool OurLambdaFunc(string text) { return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text); }`

The `.Any<T>(Func<T,bool> selector)` method expands into something like this:

```
public bool Any<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, bool> selector)
{
  foreach(var value in collection)
    if(selector(value))
      return true;  // Something matched the selector method's criteria.

  // Nothing matched our selector method's criteria.
  return false;
}
```